# Fixed width height causes unnecessary scroll - Chrome Extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension with fixed window of 360px640px dimensions. My content div has less than 640px height, it still adds scroll. I don't understand. I added the following CSS to HTML, body tags.

```
 body{ width: 360px; height: 640px; overflow:hidden}

<html>
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
    <style>
  body{ width: 360px; height: 640px; overflow:hidden}

    </style>
</head>
```

## Chrome extention

Comment: Please see the html code above

Comment: Is this the whole html? Accordingly there should be an element which is larger than the body, which is causing the page to scroll. Find that element!

Comment: I am having the same issue somewhere else. Hence I created the above test mark up to see if I can reproduce the same scrolling issues. Apparently the test mark up with just H1 also causes the scroll. This issue only happens in Chrome extension.

Comment: Also add    `overflow:hidden` to html

Comment: @VipulSharma no luck

Comment: Maximum size of the extension popup is 800x600px but your 640px is bigger. The outmost container element must be 600px or less if you don't want scrollbars.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum dimensions for Chrome extension pop window are 800 X 600 px. If the container width or height more than these dimensions will result in scrolling.